# Generic.xaml not used in custom WPF control

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am using Visual Studio express, so do not have the WPF Custom Control Library project type.  Using snoop I can see that the style is not used at all, however if I put the style in Window.Resources it works.

My structure is as follows:

```
MyApp.Controls
- Themes (Folder)
    - generic.xaml (build action "Content", no custom tool)
MyApp
  *References MyApp.Controls*
```

At the end of MyApp.Controls.Properties.Assemblyinfo.cs I have:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

generic.xaml content:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:LogView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:LogView}">
                    <TextBlock>Hello!</TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The log view class itself has the following:

```
public class LogView : Control
{
    static LogView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(LogView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LogView)));
    }
```

Any ideas what may still be missing, or is something I've done wrong?

Comment: I believe `generic.xaml` needs to have build action "Resource" to function correctly.

Comment: @dlev Still doesn't work as Resource :(

Comment: Ah, I think I was mixed up with custom Phone controls. *Page* build action should work (possibly with Custom Tool "MSBuild:Compile").

Comment: As simple as that! No need for the MSBuild:Compile. Thanks for your help.